# ndb.get_multi returning AssertionError

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Over the last 48 hours or so my small python GAE app has started getting AssertionErrors from ndb.get_multi calls.

Full traceback is appended, and the errors are being generated on the production server in _BaseValue's __init__ on line 734 of /base/data/.../ndb/model.py, and the failing assertion is b_val is not None with message "Cannot wrap None"

The error doesn't appear to be related to a particular entity or entities, but I've only seen it with one entity type so far (yet to test others).

The get_multi call is for only up to a dozen keys, and the error is intermittent so that repeating it will sometimes succeed. Or not...

I'm not seeing this error via remote shell, but I note that my local install is 1.9.23 while the log entry says the production server is 1.9.25 (GoogleAppEngineLauncher says my local install is up to date)

I'm adding a workaround to catch the exception and iterate through the keys to get them individually but I'm still seeing an upstream warning about a "suspended generator get" on line 744 of context.py.

The warning appears on the first get of this entity type from the list, for at least 2 different lists of keys (as well as preceding the AssertionError).

I don't want to have to wrap all get_multi calls in this way.

What's going on?

---

TRACEBACK:

```
Cannot wrap None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~thegapnetball/115.386356111937586421/handlers/assess.py", line 50, in get
    rs = ndb.get_multi(t.players)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3905, in get_multi
    for future in get_multi_async(keys, **ctx_options)]
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 326, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 372, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 751, in get
    pbs = entity._to_pb(set_key=False).SerializePartialToString()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3147, in _to_pb
    prop._serialize(self, pb, projection=self._projection)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2379, in _serialize
    projection=projection)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1405, in _serialize
    values = self._get_base_value_unwrapped_as_list(entity)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1175, in _get_base_value_unwrapped_as_list
    wrapped = self._get_base_value(entity)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1163, in _get_base_value
    return self._apply_to_values(entity, self._opt_call_to_base_type)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1335, in _apply_to_values
    value[:] = map(function, value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1217, in _opt_call_to_base_type
    value = _BaseValue(self._call_to_base_type(value))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 734, in \__init__
    assert b_val is not None, "Cannot wrap None"
AssertionError: Cannot wrap None
```

Comment: Problem seems to have gone as mysteriously as it came, but I would still appreciate any suggestions or advice in case it reappears.

Comment: Nope, still there... :(

Comment: Have you changed you model class recently ? also have you tried fetching each of these keys with individual gets ?  The problem may not be to do with get_multi but the underlying entitites

Comment: Based on the error I believe Tim is right that there is something wrong with one (or more) of the individual entities. This may be a bug in ndb, can you send me an email at pcostello@google.com? I'd like to get some more info on this.

Comment: @PatrickCostello is there any issue tracker or anything similar about this issue? We hit the same thing yesterday, so this could still be an issue in 2018

Answer (score 8):

Tim Hoffman and Patrick Costello put me on the right track to solve this.

I incremented version to protect some changes but took longer to finish than I expected.

One change added a repeated StructuredProperty to a model derived from ndb.Model, and I put several entities with the extra property (about 30 out of 1100 total).

The previous version without the extra property was still the default and was being lightly used, so the entities became just inconsistent enough to produce the intermittent AssertionError.

The main lesson is to take note of the recommendations in Google's schema update article, particularly changing the underlying parent to Expando and/or disabling datastore edits until any migration is complete.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema

The fix was to add the property to the previous version, get all the entities and then put them.

Thanks Tim and Patrick for the pointer!

Comment: big thanks for documenting this -- we hit the same thing

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: I haven’t kept up with appengine updates so I have no idea if this is still applicable, but archive.org has the old update article: https://web.archive.org/web/20181111035113/https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema